# Data Source/Data Set can't find Report Parameter for Property Binding

Tags: birt

I have a Report Parameter called "jndiURL" (I've tried other names, the same problem occurs)  that is passed into a BIRT Report. In the Properties of my Data Source, I go to Property Binding and set the JNDI URL to:

```
params["jndiURL"].value
```

I accept the changes and the window closes without errors.  Then I create a data set, set up a query, preview the results and accept the changes.  At this point I get an error that says:

> Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error: Report parameter "jndiURL" does not exist.
>    Script source: <inline>, line: 0, text:
>   params["jndiURL"].value

After this error is closed the data set can no longer resolve itself (i.e. the list of available fields disappears).  Removing the Property Binding in the Data Source allows you to create Data Sets normally, but as soon as you add the Property Binding again, the data set is unresolvable.

I'm taking over report creation from someone else who is no longer here and this is how their reports are all set up so they might have been using another version of BIRT or found a work around.  I believe one solution is to add a script to set this property when the report runs, but I would like to avoid that.

Any ideas?

I'm using BIRT 2.6.2 for Eclipse (All-in-One version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in the latest version of BIRT.  [If you cannot update BIRT to the latest version, a patch exists for 2.6.2](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=340560)